# MySQl field type

Tags: mysql

I have a table in my db where I store records of user actions. Currently the column that contains user IDs is set to int(11), however i am making some changes to my code where I will be adding temporary user IDs.

To differentiate the temporary IDs from the regular ones, I prepend 0 to the id.

Example: 4 -- regular user; 023 -- temporary

However when I populate this ID into ym table the zero gets discarded. What field type do I need to change it to to keep all IDs in tact?

Answer (score 2):

You could change it to an varchar if you want to prefix the id's with a 0

But you might want to try this.
Add a new column:

```
ALTER TABLE `your_table`  ADD COLUMN `temp_id` INT(11) NULL AFTER `original_id`;
```

Then migrate your id's

```
UPDATE `your_table` SET temp_id = `original_id`;
```

Comment: I was leaning to varchar myself. This column does not have index, no unique and does not have an auto-increment. It is purely to associate some action with user.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have to go with a varchar field but note that this will eliminate your auto_increment if you have one.

Answer (score 0):

The user ID is an int and ints are binary numbers.  A leading zero is the SAME as the number without a leading zero.

I would suggest negating the number to indicate a temporary id.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a 0 before an int  ( (01 == 1) -- mostly but I'm not going to get into the vagaries of that).

Just add a type column.  You can always drop the column later.

Comment: Check out the solution below mine.  I think that's what you really want.